# How to use Barrier to limit number of simultaneous threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using multithreading in python to send HTTP requests, but if I send too many simultanesouly, my request gets blocked.

So I would like to send the requests 5 by 5. This is what I tried to do, but this doesn't seem to work.
Where in that code am I supposed to use the barrier, and what code is missing?

```
b = threading.Barrier(5)

def send_request(arg1,arg2)
    # send HTTP request here

for task in tasks:
      thread = Thread(target=send_request,args=(arg1,arg2))
      thread.start()
      threads.append(thread)

for t in threads:
     t.join()
```

Comment: A Semaphore might be more suitable for this use case. Basically, you can issue a certain number of "permits" for the code to enter a section by requiring each thread to acquire the semaphore before executing the request, optionally waiting some period, and then release the semaphore once done. https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects

Comment: @nickklon Agree.  A Barrier(5) will block the first 4 threads that try to pass it; when the 5th thread tries to pass it they are all released.  However, neither Barrier or Semaphore will do anything at all unless you *use* it, which this code does not do.  Instantiating it does nothing.

Comment: Alternatively you could a ThreadPool and limit the number of workers to 5.

Answer (score 0):

Semaphores are more suitable to this:
no more than N (=5) threads can acquire the semaphore concurrently:

```
import threading 
sem = threading.Semaphore(5)

def send_request(arg1,arg2):
    try:
        sem.acquire()
        # send HTTP request here
        ...
    finally:
        sem.release()

for task in tasks:
      thread = Thread(target=send_request,args=(arg1,arg2))
      thread.start()
      threads.append(thread)

for t in threads:
     t.join()
```

Although there are other design issues in this code, it is good enough
for a one-time fire and "do-it" script. Usually we don't want to create a lot of disposable threads, just to discard them (and certainly not keep them around until all threads have been fired).

The more usual pattern for long-running processes, or really high-load
scripts is to use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` - which will keep a limited amount of threads to execute more than one task each.

Comment: As the person who answered the previous query by this user.  He specifically said he wanted 5 queries to go out at once, and then to send out five more once those were all done.  Hence my recommendation for a Barrier.

If, one the other hand, the goal was simply to limit the number of outstanding requests to 5, then a Semaphore is the more appropriate limiter.